# How to make a border from a view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to make a 2px border from a view, but the border only accepts a `ShapeStyle`. I'm trying to do something like:

```
let specialRadialGradient = GeometryReader { geometry in
    RadialGradient(
        gradient: Gradient(
            stops: [
                .init(color: Color("gradient1").opacity(0.5), location: 0),
                .init(color: Color("gradient2").opacity(0.5), location: 1)
            ]
        ),
        center: .init(x: 0.1432, y: 0.7254
        startRadius: .zero,
        endRadius: geometry.size.width * 0.75
    )
    .background(Color.brandPrimary)
}

Text("Abc")
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
  .padding()
  .border(specialRadialGradient, 2)
```

However, since the `specialRadialGradient` view is wrapped in a `GeometryReader` to handle the radial gradient properly in all ratio sizes, it doesn't compile. How can I cut out a 2px border out of `specialRadialGradient` and apply it to the background of the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of border it can be done with composition of background and blending mode.

Here is a demo of possible approach. Tested with Xcode 14 / iOS 16

**(gradient colours just replicated for demo)*
[image: demo]

```
let borderWidth = 2.0
Text("Abc")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .padding()
    .background(
        specialRadialGradient
            .overlay(Rectangle().padding(borderWidth)    // << here !!
                .blendMode(.destinationOut))
            .compositingGroup()   // << important !!
    )
```

[Test code on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestGradientBorder.swift)